# Why does angular-file-upload result in 400 Bad Request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to follow the [angular-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-upload) example from the NPM site but it is resulting in a 400 Bad Request error, although I am not sure why. Could it be an error on the server end?

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModelObj">
<input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
<button ng-click="upload.abort()">Cancel Upload</button>
```

My Module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['kendo.directives', 'ui.router', 'angularFileUpload', 'data']);
```

My Controller:

```
myApp.controller('mainController',['$scope', 'dataService', '$upload', function($scope, dataService, $upload){

 $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
  var file = $files[i];
  $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
    url: myURL,
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
            'Authorization': 'bearer ' + token,
            'Accept': "application/json", 
            'Content-Type': undefined
          },
    data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
    file: file 

   }).progress(function(evt) {
     console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
   }).success(function(data, status){
     console.log(data);
   }).error(function(data, status){
     console.log(status);
   });
 };
}]);
```

I am just uploading a single file for now.

Any help would be appreciated, I find debugging http requests pretty tricky.

**UPDATE**

It was a matter of including the right fields in 'data'. The structure below solved the problem. May my stupidity be a lesson for all: always make sure you know what data the server-side is expecting.

```
 url: myURL,
 method: 'POST', 
 headers: {
          'Authorization': 'bearer ' + token,
          'Accept': "application/json",
          'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: {
       'name': 'test',
       'files': file 
 }
```

Comment: I don't like 'Content-Type': undefined. Can you try removing it?

Comment: @DmitryK Unfortunately, removing that line still results in a 400 error.

Comment: "Could it be an error on the server end?" Yes it could. What does the server's error log say? While it may not help, it's at least a good place to start...

Comment: Is it possible that the browser itself is kicking out the request because it can tell there's something malformed about it? Because there are no POST requests registered in the server's error log. I tried the same thing with curl in the command line and for that an error did register in the server log (an "error retrieving stream").